# OpenGL got black screen with glOrtho lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So, i making a 2d platformer. I got the texture, controls and everything fine until i decided to make the game to have a scrolling camera. I've read somewhere that said to use glOrtho to move and zoom the camera but when i call glOrtho my screen turns black i know i did something wrong but don't know what to do.

I got this before the game loop:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
glOrtho(0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
*enabling texture_2d and others
```

and i got this on the game loop to make the camera follows the player:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
xOff = player.x - GAME.WIDTH / 2;
yOff = player.y - GAME.HEIGHT / 2;
glOrtho(xOff, xOff + GAME_WIDTH, yOff + GAME_HEIGHT, yOff, 1, -1);
```

But it gives me black screen.. it is fine when i change the values on the first call of glOrtho though.. i already search this prob on google but can't find any help?

EDIT: here's the main class

```
package com.org.Game;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

import com.org.Game.Graphics.Draw;
import com.org.Game.Graphics.Sprite;
import com.org.Game.Graphics.Spritesheet;
import com.org.Game.Level.Level;
import com.org.Game.Level.Entity.Mob.Player;

public class Main {

    private static String title = "Platformer";
    private static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static int GAME_WIDTH = 320, GAME_HEIGHT = 240;

    private boolean exit = false;
    private long lastFPS;
    private int fps;
    private long lastFrame;
    private long delta;
    private boolean fpscap = true;

    private Level lvl;
    private Player player;
    private int xOff, yOff;

    public Main() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT));
            Display.setTitle(title);
            Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
            DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();
            for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++) {
                if (modes[i].getWidth() == WINDOW_WIDTH && modes[i].getHeight() == WINDOW_HEIGHT && modes[i].getFrequency() == 60 && modes[i].isFullscreenCapable()) {
                    Display.setDisplayMode(modes[i]);
                    System.out.println(modes[i].getWidth() + " " + modes[i].getHeight() + " " + modes[i].getBitsPerPixel() + " " + modes[i].getFrequency() + " " + modes[i].isFullscreenCapable());
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Display.setFullscreen(true);
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        glLoadIdentity();
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        glOrtho(0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);

        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_DST_COLOR);

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

        lvl = new Level();
        lvl.loadLevel("level0.dat");
        if (lvl == null) System.out.println("NULL");
        player = new Player(16, 16, Sprite.cobalt, lvl);

        start();

        Spritesheet.tiles.tex.release();
        Spritesheet.bg_day.tex.release();
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int a;

    private void render() {
        Draw.clearScreen();

        glLoadIdentity();
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glOrtho(xOff, xOff + GAME_WIDTH, yOff + GAME_HEIGHT, yOff, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        Draw.setTexture(Spritesheet.bg_day);
        Draw.drawBackground(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, Spritesheet.bg_day);

        Draw.setTexture(Spritesheet.tiles);
        lvl.renderLevel(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, xOff, yOff);

        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        player.render();
    }

    private void update(long delta) {
        player.update(delta);
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) exit = true;
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_Z)) fpscap = true;
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_X)) fpscap = false;
    }

    public void start() {
        lastFPS = getTime();
        getDelta();

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested() && !exit) {
            getDelta();

            xOff = (int) player.x - GAME_WIDTH / 2;
            yOff = (int) player.y - GAME_HEIGHT / 2;

            render();
            update(delta);

            updateFPS();
            Display.update();
            if (fpscap) Display.sync(120);
        }
    }

    private void getDelta() {
        long now = getTime();
        delta = now - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = now;
    }

    private void updateFPS() {
        fps++;
        if (getTime() - lastFPS > 1000) {
            lastFPS += 1000;
            Display.setTitle(title + " FPS: " + fps);
            fps = 0;
        }
    }

    private long getTime() {
        return Sys.getTime() * 1000 / Sys.getTimerResolution();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

Comment: So you're putting an ortho projection matrix on the modelview stack too?  Why?

Comment: so you're saying i need to switch to gl_projection before the second glOrtho again?

Comment: @Greffin28: there are a couple of potential problems with your approach, but without further code, it is hard to tell what is going on. If you put that matrix onto both stacks, they will be applied twice. And this will not give you the result you expect, `glOrtho` just creates a combined scale-and-translate matrix.

Comment: @derhass so do you would like to see the code? and if the second glOrtho combined the previous state, how could i make the camera following the player with glOrtho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you do not change the matrix mode to GL_PROJECTION before switching the orthographic projection, as far as I can tell - as your second code snippet does not have the matrix mode state change. So, try this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
xOff = player.x - GAME.WIDTH / 2;
yOff = player.y - GAME.HEIGHT / 2;
glOrtho(xOff, xOff + GAME_WIDTH, yOff + GAME_HEIGHT, yOff, 1, -1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Keep in mind this code snippet WILL reset your transformation matrix, so any glTransform() or glRotate() calls or glScale() calls will of course be nullified, but since this is at the start of your game loop and is run every tick I suspect that this should not be a problem.

Comment: Well, you are calling glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) which clears the screen.

Comment: wait.. what.. but i called the glOrtho after i cleared the screen doesn't it make any changes?

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused. Can you either give me a pastebin with your rendering loop or add a bit more code to your question?

Comment: there you go the main class

Comment: Hmmm. Try putting glLoadIdentity() after glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION), I edited my answer to show what I mean. I believe it only affects the current matrix.

Comment: @SDLeffler: Yes, glLoadIdentity only affects the matrix selected with the most recent call to glMatrixMode.

Comment: No problem! :) If you're going to be doing changing orthos a lot, you might create a helper function for it - I don't know if you're going to use shaders but when I do things like multipass rendering by binding a shader and repeatedly flip-flopping through FBOs if I'm going to do projection matrix changes.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code: You're doing "OpenGL initialization". Why? OpenGL is a state machine, it doesn't get initialized. You put OpenGL into the state you need it to be, right when you need it. Most of the OpenGL calls in the constructor are unnecessary and have no effect. Most of the OpenGL stuff should be done in only the render function.

For the render method try this:

```
private void render() {
            // glViewport does not depend on the matrix state
    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    Draw.clearScreen();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(xOff, xOff + GAME_WIDTH, yOff + GAME_HEIGHT, yOff, 1, -1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

            // probably don't want to blend the background
            // actually get your blending stuff right, I removed it entirely
            // because it's completely unclear from your code what you want
            // to blend which way
    glDisable(GL_BLEND); 
    Draw.setTexture(Spritesheet.bg_day);
    Draw.drawBackground(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, Spritesheet.bg_day);

    Draw.setTexture(Spritesheet.tiles);
    lvl.renderLevel(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, xOff, yOff);

            // probably needs its texture set.
    player.render();
}
```

Comment: oh yeah that works too.. but i might be more comfortable with calling something once that will never be changed again.. oh yeah and thanks for reminding me to disable blend before background :)

Comment: @Greffin28: The cost of setting the projection matrix is so small, that the benefits of setting it every display call hugely outweigh it. Also sooner or later you'll end up in a situation where you need to change projection parameters several times throughout rendering a frame and if your program was built around "set projection only once" it ends up becoming a huge mess of trying to keep track what changes which thing in which order. Trust me, you want to reset the projection rendering each frame.

Comment: no i didn't mean the projection matrix but the other like enabling gl_texture_2d

Comment: @Greffin28: Texture enable state is even more volatile than projection setup. It's commonplace to render geometry without textures beside geometry with textures. In general the whole idea of "one-time state setting" in OpenGL is completely misguided. All OpenGL state should be set from a clean slate at the beginning of each drawing iteration. The only one-time initialization is for data objects which don't change their contents, like texture images or static-draw VBOs.

Comment: ohhh okay now i understand a little more about opengl :p